# How can I access the information shown in git log --stat using only plumbing commands?

Tags: git, scripting, git-log

I'm writing a script that uses the insertion + deletion information in `git log --stat`, but I've realised that I should be using [plumbing commands](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_low_level_commands_plumbing), while git-log is a [porcelain command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_high_level_commands_porcelain).

What plumbing command or commands can I use to get access to the same information that git-log is using to produce those stats?

Comment: By the way, which language are you using for scripting? Are you doing this in pure Bash? Git has various 3rd-party scripting libraries available, they're all part of the [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) project. There are libraries in Ruby, Python, C#, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some porcelain commands also have "plumbing modes" that generate machine-parseable output (e.g. [`git status -z`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html#_porcelain_format)).

Similarly, [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) has a "machine-friendly" version of the `--stat` option:

> ```
> --numstat
> ```
>
> Similar to `--stat`, but shows number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two "-" instead of saying "0 0".

There might be pure plumbing commands that let you avoid using `log` altogether though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a good suggestion and I might use it, but the recommendation seems to be to not use porcelain command output in scripts at all, as it is liable to change.